# Cannot Install libpng12-0 on Debian

Tags: debian, apt

Anytime I attempt to install `libpng12-0` with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libpng12-0
```

I get this returned:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-base libavformat53 libcdaudio1 libgcrypt11 libgnutls-deb0-28 libgnutls26 libgsoap5
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-0 libhogweed2 libjasper1 libmimic0
  libmpg123-0 libnettle4 libpostproc52 libqt4-dbus libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-xml libqtcore4 libqtdbus4
  libqtgui4 librtmp0 libslv2-9 libsoundtouch0 libswscale2 libtasn1-3 libuv1 libvncserver0 libwildmidi1 qdbus
  qt-at-spi qtchooser qtcore4-l10n virtualbox-dkms
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpng12-0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 173 kB of archives.
After this operation, 273 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://debian.cc.lehigh.edu/debian jessie/main amd64 libpng12-0 amd64 1.2.50-2+deb8u2 [173 kB]
Fetched 173 kB in 0s (493 kB/s)    
(Reading database ... 182049 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpng12-0:amd64 (1.2.50-2+deb8u2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to install new version of '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0': No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have NO IDEA how to work around this. I do have `libpng16-16` installed, but I don't see why that would cause an issue. I've tried everything from downloading the .deb manually and installing it to trying to symlink the `libpng16-16` `so` to that location. All of it gave me no luck.

Anyone have any advice?

Further information: any attempt to symlink another `.so` into the path provided (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0`) results in the deletion of that symlink and the same error. The `.so` I was attempting to symlink as a fix, was `libpng.so` which is provided by `libpng-dev` (or `libpng16-16`).

Comment: Try `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u2_amd64.deb`, and then rerun `apt`.

Comment: I've tried this and `apt-get clean` multiple times, in addition to grabbing the `.deb` directly off of the deb packaging site. Did it again, still no go, same error.

Comment: You could potentially grab the [source](ftp://ftp.simplesystems.org/pub/libpng/png/src/libpng12/) and build it. I'd suggest 1.2.56 (at a minimum), there is a list of vulnerabilities in earlier versions [here](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html).

Comment: I think I'm going to give this another few days, or until I DIRELY need it, and then just build from source. This is driving me nuts and I can't even figure out what file or directory is missing during the unpack...

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0`? It's likely that the symlink there is broken, and that you need to manually fix it.

Comment: Output of `sudo ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0` is simply: `ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0': No such file or directory`, which is what I expect since `libpng12-0` isn't installed, so I wouldn't expect the symlink to already exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have this resolved now. I went to the Debian forums and asked my question [here](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=130905&p=631940#p631940), where a helpful member pointed out that `libpng12-0` isn't available for Stretch (should have specified my OS version earlier, sorry). I was trying to install the Jessie version, and that just... doesn't work with Stretch right now. There's a version of `libpng12-0` in Sid, currently. It should make it's way to Stretch in the near future to solve this issue.

In the meantime, I abandoned installing the Jessie `libpng12-0` package, and just did the Wheezy package, which is version `1.2.49` instead of `1.2.50`, which worked like a charm. Until `1.2.50` is out for Stretch, I recommend installing Wheezy's `1.2.49`.

Thanks again for the help to everyone who replied and commented, you all are truly wonderful human beings!

Comment: I needed this to install the Unity Editor on Debian Stretch, the Wheezy 1.2.49 version worked. Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell me how you installed the wheezy package? I've never had to do this sort of thing before.

Comment: I don't know what the exact version you need to install is, so that changes the output of the command, but you generally want to follow the instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/428772/how-to-install-specific-version-of-some-package/428778, which will help you find the right version. Just look for the one that says `wheezy` where `saucy/main` is in that example link. Then just install it with: `apt-get install libpng12-0=$VER`. Paste `apt-cache policy libpng12-0` output if you hit issues.

Answer (score 3):

You can download the libpng12-0 from.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/i386/libpng12-0/download for 386 architecture

and

http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download for 64 bits.

Comment: While I normally hate grabbing `.deb`'s for other distros, I manually downloaded the 64 bit `.deb` for Ubuntu and receive the same error as described in the OP. Thanks for trying though!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there's something a bit messed up with `libpng12-0`; it installs its `.so` in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` (on `amd64`), but also drops a link in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` — and I think that's what's breaking here.

On my system everything is installed correctly (`libpng16-16` and `libpng12-0`), but I also have `libpng-dev` installed (version 1.6), and that allows the `libpng12-0` link to be resolved. If my theory is correct, you should be able to do

```
apt-get install libpng-dev
apt-get install libpng12-0
```

and have a working `libpng12`...

Comment: That was a really solid theory, because I didn't have `libpng-dev` installed. So, I have now installed it (`1.6.26-6` is the exact version) and tried to rerun the install for `libpng12-0`, unfortunately, I received the same error =(. Any other ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've tried removing and reinstalling `libpng12-0` on my own system and it works fine, with and without `libpng-dev`.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, but I figured it out. I'm running Stretch (testing), which doesn't have `libpng12-0` out officially. I was trying to install Jessie's version (`1.2.50`). When I installed Wheezy's version (`1.2.49`), everything was fixed and it works like a charm. Appreciate your time though!

Comment: I know, `libpng16-16` is only available in testing and unstable, so I figured you were running at least testing; and `libpng12-0` isn't available there any more. I tested with the Jessie version too... But if the Wheezy version works, that's good. You should probably try to get rid of the need for `libpng12-0` entirely though, it does have a few security holes!

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit (as superuser) `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add a line `deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian wheezy main` then save this and enter next command `sudo apt-get install libpng12-0` and your issue may be solved

Comment: Good idea, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally install this file into my kali build.

I had to download "libpng-1.2.49" the file that runs on debian 7 "wheezy" as a .tar.gz file.

extract it through the normal methods than using the readme was able to successfully install the file and get the desired result i was looking for.